# Unable to print username from slack as "@John" and also how to close python file in linux without entering cntrl+c manually

Tags: python, mysql, slack, slack-api

> Q1) Unable to print username from slack as "@John"  instead its printing "WLCLZ2LDP"
>
> So for variable "username" it should print slack username ( for example : JohnDoe) but instead printing randomized letter as WLCLZ2LDP

code

```
@slack.RTMClient.run_on(event='message')
def say_hello(**payload):
    try:
        ##0 get clients and payload
        logging.info('msg received')

        data = payload['data']
        web_client = payload['web_client']
        rtm_client = payload['rtm_client']

        ##0 - 1 Check if it is the first msg, not replied msg by me
        # print(data)
        if data.get('text') == None:
            logging.info('This msg is my replied msg.')
            return False
        ##0-2 Get channel info
        channel_id = data['channel']
        thread_ts = data['ts']
        global user
        user = data['user']

        ##1 get scenario submsg
        msg = data['text']
        retVal = analysis_msg(msg)
.
.
.
.code continuation 
.
.
.
.mycursor = mydb.cursor()
for value in submsg:
  print(value)
fulfilment=submsg[0]
sku=submsg[1]
environment=submsg[2]
payment=submsg[3]
ts = time.time()
date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
orderNumber=res
username=user

print(fulfilment)
print(sku)
print(environment)
print(payment)
print(username)
print(orderNumber)

sqlformula = "INSERT INTO orderDetails (fulfilment,sku,environment,payment,orderNumber,date,user) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"

#order=("sth",3643387,"sftqa2","AMEX")
#mycursor.execute(sqlformula,order)

mycursor.execute(sqlformula,(fulfilment,sku,environment,payment,orderNumber,date,username))

mydb.commit()
mydb.close()
```

Output

Below output I need to get slack username but i m getting randomized letter

```
spu
3646989
mq1
AMEX
WLCLZ2LDP
"200002086748"
```

Edited code

```
@slack.RTMClient.run_on(event='message')
def say_hello(**payload):
    try:
        ##0 get clients and payload
        logging.info('msg received')
        data = payload['data']
        web_client = payload['web_client']
        rtm_client = payload['rtm_client']
        ##0 - 1 Check if it is the first msg, not replied msg by me
        # print(data)
        if data.get('text') == None:
            logging.info('This msg is my replied msg.')
            return False
        ##0-2 Get channel info
        channel_id = data['channel']
        thread_ts = data['ts']

        global user
        user = data['user']
        msg = data['text']
        retVal = analysis_msg(msg)

        response = web_client.users_list()
        assert(response['ok'])
        user_map = {x['id']: x['name'] for x in response['members']}
        global user_name
        user_name = user_map[user] if user in user_map else None
        print(user_name)
```

**Case 1:** Output of edited code  - When some other user tries from their machine getting as "None" (not expected

```
spu
2469048
sftqa3
AMEX
None
BBY01-200002096736
```

**Case 2:** Output of edited code : when i run from with my machine Iam able to see my aid ie A6002043 ( is expected)

```
spu
2469048
sftqa3
VISA
a6002043
BBY01-200002096040
```

Comment: Those are two unrelated topics put together in one questions. Would suggest to split this up into two question. I will answer the one regarding Slack below.

Comment: Hey thanks Erik! , yes my bad those are not randomized string , same id comes up whenever I send message from my user.  Will try out your below solution

Answer (score 2):

Please allow me to clear up two misunderstandings:

- Those are not "randomized letters", but user IDs.
- Events do not contain usernames, only IDs of the users.

To get the username you need to call the API method [users.list](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.list) to get the list of users. With that you can map IDs to users names.

Here is an example code how to get the user name for a user ID:

```
slack_token = os.environ['SLACK_TOKEN']
response = client.users_list()
assert(response['ok'])
user_map = {x['id']: x['name'] for x in response['members']}
user_name = user_map[user_id] if user_id in user_map else None
print(user_name)
```

Comment: I have edited my question , can you please help , i m able to see my aid of my machine but if some one else run i see the value as none